# How to print values in SelfLocalizer.cpp in Nav2d

Tags: ros, ros-info, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to analyse the Algorithms in SelfLocalizer node which is Particle Filter, Beam range finder, and Field range finder model. I understand the theory behind it but I want to see what is coming out in some of the equations.
I have tried to add `std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;` , `printf ("%s \n", "TEST");`   and `ROS_INFO("usage: add_two_ints_client X Y");` in the code, then make the project and then run one of  the launch file. I can see a lot of messages and parameters are printet in Terminal, but not the the one that I was expecting. Can anyone help me with that, or how can I read the value of a specific equation ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228091/how-to-print-values-in-selflocalizer.cpp-in-nav2d/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2016-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To be able to print messages on terminal, in launch file you should add `output="screen"` to the relevant `<node>` tag.

Also you can view `ROS_INFO` messages on `rqt_console`.

**In reply to OP's comment:**

It should be like this:

```
<node name="SelfLocalizer" pkg="nav2d_localizer" type="localizer" output="screen">
  <remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>
  <param name="min_particles" type="int" value="5000"/>
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2016-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thanks but it  does not work if it should be like this in launch file:
`<node name="SelfLocalizer" pkg="nav2d_localizer" type="localizer">`
`<remap from="scan" to="base_scan"/>`
 `<param name="min_particles" type="int" value="5000"/>`
`output="screen"` `</node>`

**Comment by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on 2016-03-03**:
Thank you very much, now I can se a lot of printouts  :D

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-03-03**:
Glad it helped! :)

**Comment by [zzzZuo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25453/zzzzuo/) on 2016-05-13**:
Thanks you so much for sharing!

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2016-05-24**:
You're welcome!